# The human body is 60% water. (60% quantifier float?)

Tags: quantifiers

> (1) *The human body is 60% water*.

Note that (1) means "60% of the human body is water".

In (1), *60%* is a quantifier of the subject but resides within the predicate. Is this a type of quantifier float?

But I've never seen any reference (grammar or paper) where "x percent" is shown as an example of quantifier float.

If this is a valid example of quantifier float, please show me some reference. If not, please explain why it's not a valid example.

Comment: In case someone asks: https://www.ifioque.com/grammar/quantifier-floating This is the first time I have heard of a "quantifier float"

Comment: Offhand, it seems to me the syntactic affordances of  **60%** are the same as those for **[a] half, [a] quarter,...** - which aren't the same as those for **all, both, each,...**

Comment: What is your definition of quantifier float? Quantifier float pertains to  *all*, *both*, and *each*, where the quantifier can be moved away from its noun and into an adverbial position within the same sentence.

Comment: Such a terrible example given bodies and water.

Comment: It's probably floating if the fat is 30% or more.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Isn't the _60%_ moved away from its noun and into an adverbial position within the same sentence?

Comment: Looks like you moved it to the subject position. In any case, if you have to add *of*, it’s not the same sentence, and it’s not a float.

Comment: @TinfoilHat If it's not a type of quantifier float, how would you explain its position within the predicate?

Comment: Even though your examples might be semantically equivalent, 60% doesn’t function the same in both sentences. Here, *all* is floated: [*All of those animals are horses. Those animals are all horses.*] Here, *most* can’t float: [*Most of those animals are horses.* *\*Those animals are most horses.*] Same here: [*60% of voters are angry.* ? *Voters are 60% angry.*] And here: [*A mule is 50% horse.* *\*50% horse is a mule.*] And so on.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thanks for the _voters_ example, which shows that x% is not as freely movable. But at least in OP's case, it did float, didn't it? // The ungrammatical *_50% horse is a mule_ just goes to show, I think, that _50%_ doesn't modify _horse_, which makes it more like a quantifier float, don't you think?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a case of floating quantifier according to "[*FLOATING QUANTIFIERS, PARTITIVES AND DISTRIBUTIVITY*
Jack Hoeksema
University of Groningen](http://www.let.rug.nl/hoeksema/flq.pdf)".

> The general distribution of floating quantifiers shows strong similarities with that of bound
> anaphora such as reciprocals and reflexives (as noted for example in Oosthuizen 1989). Thus,
> they require an appropriate antecedent within the same clause:
>
> (4a)      
> The kids were all happy that their parents had left.
>            (4b)       The kids were happy that their parents had all left.
>
> For example, in sentence (4b), the floating quantifier *all* must have the expression *their
> parents* as its antecedent, and not *the kids*.

> 1. I am assuming that we can distinguish the use of *all* in (4) from its use in (i) below, were
>    it means something like *completely* and can have a singular antecedent:
>
> (i)          John was all wet.

Note that "60%" does not have "the human body" for antecedent.

Comment: Are you suggesting OP's _60%_ is like _all_ in (i) where _all_ modifies the adjective _wet_?

Comment: @JK2 Yes, it seems a stretch. 'The human body is 60% water' is notionally part of a statement 'A consists of 60% X, 30% Y and 10% Z' say. This is very different from 'My body is hairy all over'.

Comment: *The human body is 60% water.* - grammatic. *60% of the human body is water.* - grammatic. Inverting the copula - *Water is 60% of the human body* - grammatic.  *60% water is the human body* - not grammatic. This is normal for quantifier float, yes? And I hate the 4a, 4b example. *all happy* and *all left* are two different *alls*. It has to be *all the kids* and *all left* for this argument. Being *all happy* just means all of you is happy, not all of you are happy.

Comment: @PhilSweet *grammatic* makes me thing of **grammatik**.

Comment: @JK2   That is what I believe; for instance, even if "50% wet" is not a proper formulation in some cases, "half wet with something" is found often enough, and there is a semantic correspondence between the two (both indicate a level of wetness).  "Half" in both "half wet" and "half water" is an adverb, and so "60%" would have to be reckoned with as an adverb.

Comment: @PhilSweet It seems to me that "fully happy" is a possibility, but not the only one; I think that here it is implicit that are taken into account only those cases where context has it the other way. ("She knew that what Cassandra had said was true, that she was happy, that they were all happy." (Victoria Shorr); it is here question of the happiness of several persons, not of the intensity of each person's happiness.)

Comment: But (i) cannot mean "All of John was wet", because _all_ in (i) directly modifies _wet_ meaning "completely". In contrast, OP's (1) does mean "60% of the human body is water", and it doesn't modify _water_ at all.

Comment: @JK2 We have here correspondences that are less than ideal; what does it mean to say "John was all wet."? Certainly not that the matter John's made out of is wet; no, it means rather that John's clothes, while he is wearing them, are wet, or that john's skin is covered by water, and still, some other such thing that only context will make clear. If we select "John's skin was all wet." can't we say in an equivalent manner "All of John's skin was wet."? So, while your reasoning makes sense, it is not fully convincing. I agree even less with the possibility that "60%" does // (1/2)

Comment: @JK2   not modify "water". "60% water" is really an abbreviation for "water _in the proportion of 60 parts per 100 parts of body weight_"; this specifies a variable amount of water, which is still an amount. I can't understand then that in the abbreviated form there should be no determination of the noun "water". This being said, due to the complexity that you point out, and which could still be the cause for my statement to be partially wrong, I will remove it from my answer. Nevertheless, do not consider that as an end to the discussion, and add any essential comment if you like. (2/2)

Comment: Your answer's still based on the premise that OP's example is more like _John was all wet_. If _60%_ does modify _water_ in the OP, why do you think _60% water is the human body_ doesn't work, as @PhilSweet noted earlier.

Comment: @JK2 The main idea is that "60%" does not have an antecedent, not a similarity.  //  Why "60% water is the human body" is not correct has nothing to do with the question of float quantifiers, in my opinion, but is solely a matter of the particular nature of the predication: for instance, the sentence "the best student in the class is the first victim of the covid" you can interchange subject and predication in  many cases; however in sentences like "the hamp is mahogany" the interchange can only proceed from stylistic inversion (emphasis); contexts justifying that are comparatively rare.

Comment: You have not shown that "60%" does not have an antecedent.

Comment: @JK2 Right, perhaps I thought it was more or less evident, but that's a point to consider. Since "60%" can only be  a part of the body, it can't stand for the body as a whole.

Comment: I don't understand. 60% here definitely means "60% of the human body".

Comment: @JK2 I am sorry not to be able to exchange with you any longer; that will have to be the last comment addressed to you because from now on we should be diccussing in chat; as SO policies deprive me of  chat exchange on all sites in reason of a one year exclusion from the FSE (as strange as that might seem (obvious policy in the way of ensuring that SO practices and moderator decisions shouldn't be the object of contestation);  you can check my FSE account, which has been brought down to the reputation of 1.

Comment: @LPH All suspended accounts are locked at 1 point, your points will be restored at the end of the suspension period, see [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a case of quantifier float, because unlike regular quantifier float, the *60%* must appear adjacent to the substance noun. If we add more auxiliary verbs we can see this quite clearly:

1. The students might have been all studying.
2. The students might have all been studying.
3. The students might all have been studying.

But the *60%* cannot do this:

4. The body might have been 60% water.
5. *The body might have 60% been water.
6. *The body might 60% have been water.

So I think that this shows that the percentage forms a unit with *water* and not the subject.

If we change the verb, the percentage is still possible, but the paraphrase with the subject isn't:

7. This heavy cream contains 35% milk fat.
8. #35% of this heavy cream contains milk fat.

We can also use a percentage+substance as a nominal modifier, where there is no subject for the percentage to have floated from.

9. For this application, use a 40% alcohol solution.

Comment: Yes. Even 'Lettuce is largely water' pushes most POS schemas. Numbers are classed by many as distinct even from determiners (including subset quantifiers). Though equivalences like ⅖ = 0·4 = 40% illustrate that 40% is a number in at least some usages, 'the Elbonian's body is 0·4 water' is horrendous.

Comment: 1. True, the position of _60%_ is not as free as that of _all_, _both_, or _each_. But it does denote the quantity of the subject _the human body_ and still is separated from the subject. So it may not be a regular member of FQs, but why can't it be a peripheral member? 2. Just because _all_ has a non-FQ usage as in _John was all wet_ doesn't mean _all_ cannot be a FQ in other sentences. By the same logic, what exactly do your examples 7-9 prove?